# Unable to get session Cookies from Web Response

Tags: javascript, c#, httprequest, httpresponse

I want to crawl a URL to get some data. The URL is:-

```
http://www.marriott.com/reservation/availabilitySearch.mi?propertyCode=SFOAC&isSearch=true&isRateCalendar=false&flexibleDateSearchRateDisplay=false&flexibleDateLowestRateMonth=&flexibleDateLowestRateDate=&fromDate=01/02/17&toDate=01/03/17&clusterCode=&corporateCode=&groupCode=&numberOfRooms=1&numberOfGuests=1&incentiveType_Number=&incentiveType=false&marriottRewardsNumber=&useRewardsPoints=false&numberOfChildren=0&childrenAges=&numberOfAdults=1
```

When I analyzed this URL in fiddler it shows me some Cookies are passed in Http Requests. But I am unable to get those cookies.

Next URL to hit is `http://www.marriott.com/reservation/rateListMenu.mi`

When first URL is open is one of the tabs then this second URL works in browser.  But if I close the browser and navigates to second URL it re-directs to `http://www.marriott.com/reservation/expiredSession.mi`

It means that some session cookies are maintained between these two URLs.

How to get those session cookies ?

Comment: Are you doing this from C# code or from javascript? In the first case, do you use `HttpClient` or the older `HttpWebRequest`?

Comment: I am using C# code and I am using HttpWebRequest